# Insert/Update only if an entry with the primary key does not exist

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm doing some relational mapping and I'm wondering if there is a way to prevent Hibernate from updating the foreign entity table when the primary key exists, but just skip it, and only insert when the primary key does not exist.

I'll try to explain in a simple example.

Let's say I have the following 2 classes:

```
public class Building{
    @Id
    @Column
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "BuildingTypeId")
    private BuildingType buildingType;

    ...other fields, etc...
}

public class BuildingType{
    @Id
    @Column
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "Description")
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "buildingType")
    private List<Building> buildings;

    ...other fields, etc...
}
```

In my BuildingTypes table, I will already have the following entries:

```
+----------+-------------------------------------+
|    id    |             Description             |
+----------+-------------------------------------+
| CINEMA   | Some description about cinemas      |
| HOSPITAL | Some description about hospitals    |
| SHOP     | Some description about shops        |
+----------+-------------------------------------+
```

Now let's say that I'm populating my Buildings table and have a building with a new id - a THEATER, for example. Hibernate will create a new entry in my BuildingTypes table with id THEATER and null description (since I only get the id). Good.

But when I have a building from an already existing building type, like a CINEMA, it will update the CINEMA entry in the database with id - CINEMA (like the old one) and description - null (since again - I only receive the ids.)

So is there a way for Hibernate to only insert in the BuildingTypes table if the primary key (the id in this case) is not existing, and not update when the primary key exists, even if the other columns are different?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but maybe you can do this:

```
BuildingType type =...
Building building = ...

BuildingType ref = entityManager
                        .getReference(BuildingType.class, type.getId() );
building.setBuildingType( ref );
//Continue as usual
```

This only works if `BuildingType` exists already.